# My list contains a single null employee after deserializing a JSON of employees

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON using Newtonsoft. When I deserialize I have no errors but when I put every employee of the JSON in a List of employee, the list has a single element that contains an employee that has a null firstName and a null secondName.

**This is my JSON**

```
[
  {
    "employees": [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**This is my class**

```
public class employee
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is my code**

```
IList<employee> employees = new List<employee>();

string json = default(string);
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Database.json"))
{
     json = r.ReadToEnd();                
}
employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<employee>>(json);
```

Comment: Notice that there's "employees" field in the JSON, which is not supposed to be there. Your JSON structure does not match the class you want to deserialize into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation of the JSON should look like this:

```json
[
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones "
      }
]
```

The background is that there is no "employees" in your data model. Therefore, the deserialiser does not know what to do with it.

Comment: In addition to this answer, note you probably meant to call the var employees or the file name, not the head of your json and thats the mix up. 
var employees = [{...},{...}]